# Update Compiled Code instead of Replacing with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Since using Visual Studio 2008 I've had this problem.

I've recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2012, and I have yet to find this solution:
Is there any way to update the compiled code file instead of replacing the entire site?

Whenever I release my code, VS2012 always says "... Will delete all existing files."

Is there a way to simply "update existing code" instead of the entire format? Multiple people use this internal site, and I can not have any downtime while editing.

Comment: if the update takes any non-negligible amount of time, then you could end up with a mixture of old code and new code running, so it would be unstable anyway.

Comment: @IrishChieftain, then the solution will have old code in the .bin directory. I may sound cynical, but I dont want to have to compile the code locally, have to log into a remote server, delete what needs to be updated (which will then cause errors), then copy new files over... I'm sure this will also cause linking problems - in the bin folder.

Comment: I'm simply addressing the downtime issue. I would definitely heed Damien's advice though...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - on publish, there is an option to `Allow this precompiled site to be updateable` - I thought this might have something to do with it.